# How do I attach a modal to a button or image?? My code won't work properly...I see the button but the modal won't open

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, modal-dialog

I need help with the modals I've added at the bottom of my code. Not sure if I attached them wrong, or if the modal code itself is wrong. Please help!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Jane Doette</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" href="jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" href="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JaneDoette.css">
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300'  
             rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
         <img class="title-logo"   
    src="file:///Users/Diana/Documents/fvlogo.gif" class="img-responsive" 
    alt="responsive image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
         <h1 class="title-super text-thin">Jane Doette</h1>
         <h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>
        </div>
          </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <img 
    src="file:///Users/Diana/Documents/testhtml1140x350.jpg" class="img-
    responsive" alt="responsive image">
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <h2 class="text-muted">Featured Work</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <img src="file:///Users/Diana/Documents/450x300Type.jpg" 
    class="img-responsive" alt="responsive image">
         <h3>Type</h3>
         <p>
          <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" 
                             data-target="#project1">Launch Demo Modal</button>
         </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <img 
                        src="file:///Users/Diana/Documents/450x300wallpaper.jpg" 
                        class="img-responsive" class="img-responsive" 
                        alt="responsive image">
         <h3>Wallpaper</h3>
         <p>
          <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal"
                 data-target="#project1">Launch Demo Modal</button>
         </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <img src="file:///Users/Diana/Documents/450x300print.jpg" 
                        class="img-responsive" class="img-responsive" 
                        alt="responsive image">
         <h3>Print</h3>
         <p>
          <a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a>
         </p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-  
        target="#project1">
  </button>

  <!-- Modal1 -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="project1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
        labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                         <span aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-
                         only">Close</span></button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Type</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <img src="file:///Users/Diana/Documents/450x300Type.jpg"
                         class="img-responsive" alt="responsive image">
                     <p> This was my first project in this class. I learned a 
                         lot about HTML and CSS. The portfolio page looks nice, 
                         but there really isn't that much info about your 
                         projects. but putting a lot of text under the image 
                         wouldn't look nice. So adding a modal would be the best 
                         way to do this. </p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
                         dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes
                        </button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

     <!--Modal2-->
     <div class="modal fade" id="project1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
         labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                         <span aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-
                         only">Close</span></button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Type</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <img 
                         src="file:///Users/Diana/Documents/450x300Wallpaper.jpg" 
                         class="img-responsive" alt="responsive image">
                     <p> This was my first project in this class. I learned a 
                         lot about HTML and CSS. The portfolio page looks nice, 
                         but there really isn't that much info about your 
                         projects. but putting a lot of text under the image 
                         wouldn't look nice. So adding a modal would be the best 
                         way to do this. </p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
                         dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes
                        </button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

     <!--Modal3-->
     <div class="modal fade" id="project1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
        labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                         <span aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-
                         only">Close</span></button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Type</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <img  src="file:///Users/Diana/Documents/450x300Print.jpg"
                        class="img-responsive" alt="responsive image">
                     <p> This was my first project in this class. I learned a
                         lot about HTML and CSS. The portfolio page looks nice, 
                         but there really isn't that much info about your 
                         projects. but putting a lot of text under the image 
                         wouldn't look nice. So adding a modal would be the best
                         way to do this. </p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
                         dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes
                        </button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I need a button or image to be attached to the modal, I've tried with both and neither seems to work.

Comment: What libraries are you trying to use? Is this jQuery, Bootstrap,.. ? More details would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to understand what you mean by 'attaching a button to a modal', as I was able to open the modals in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsronzoh/), however I see a few errors in your markup that I believe might help you out:

- It looks like you want three separate modals on the page. However, each of these modals has the same `id` attribute (they are all `project1`). The id's must be unique.
- Once all `id` attributes are unique, change the `data-target` attribute on the button elements to it's corresponding modal's `id`.
- Not sure if you forgot to copy the whole thing, but your `doctype` declaration is incomplete.

[Here's a fixed version](https://jsfiddle.net/gsronzoh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should provide separate ID to each modal.

I assume here, you have added **bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js**

**Your HTML should be like this,**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>

  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

[**check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/kLetf1uj/1/)